# How would a Salamander's senses work?

Tags: creature-design, fire, senses

The salamander, or fire elemental, is a creature which lives inside burning fires. This is a rather unique environment for an animal to live in. Fires produce smoke, which is dark and noisome, and creates crackling sounds, all of which will baffle the senses of any inhabitants.

The salamanders have adapted to survive in natural forest fires.

Given this information, how would the salamander's senses work, compared to other animals?

Comment: More information required. What does a salamander need to sense and why? (What do they feed on, how do they procreate, what threats do they need to avoid or fight?) Do salamanders only exist in fires and if so, what happens if a fire is extinguished? (Nothing "human-like" can naturally survive in a forest fire, so must assume their biology is completely magic.)

Comment: agree with KerrAvon2055 we need more info such as does it lies flat with it's ear touching the ground or it's tongue acts like a limping animal with 3rd degree burnt?

Comment: Another point - a salamander is an actual amphibian, which in mythology has always been portrayed as lizard-like.  Calling something completely different a "salamander" is likely to cause confusion.

Comment: Can you define "work" for us? Do you mean the unit of measure in physics, or do you mean someone sitting at a typewriter doing billing, or anyone earning a paycheck? "Work" is a big word with infinite applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Infrared vision

Real-life firefighters use thermal imaging to see, since infrared light passes right through smoke.  This allows them to find people in burning buildings. It also lets them see where the fire is hottest, which also seems like a useful ability for a salamander to have - although for the opposite reason.

Many real animals, such as snakes, can detect infrared light, so it seems perfectly reasonable for salamanders to have the same ability.

One weakness of infrared vision is that cold-blooded animals are hard to see with it, since they are often the same temperature as their environment. If salamanders are the same temperature as the fire, they may be invisible to each other while actually inside the fire. If they can generate body heat though, they could be visible to each other - they could even use this for communication.